# Populate viewflipper from image from mysql database

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have a ViewFlipper populated with multiple ImageView. but now, i wanted to populate the view flipper with images from mysql database. But i don't know how to implement it.

here's my ViewFlipper.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
tools:context=".Login">
<ViewFlipper 
android:id="@+id/view_flipper" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:flipInterval="5000"   
android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left"   
android:outAnimation="@android:anim/slide_out_right"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_centerInParent="true">
<ImageView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
android:src="@drawable/login_pic1"/>
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
android:src="@drawable/login_pic2"/>
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
android:src="@drawable/login_pic3"/>
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
android:src="@drawable/login_pic4"/>
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
android:src="@drawable/login_pic5"/>
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
android:src="@drawable/pic6"/>
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
android:src="@drawable/pic7"/>

</ViewFlipper>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Button btn_login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    Button btn_signup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create);
    final EditText txt_username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    final EditText txt_password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);
    flipper.startFlipping();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
    Bitmap circularBitmap = ImageConverter.getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, 80);
    ImageView circularImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo);
    circularImageView.setImageBitmap(circularBitmap);

    View.OnClickListener login_click = new View.OnClickListener(){
```

//login form validation

```
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String user = txt_username.getText().toString();
            String pass = txt_password.getText().toString();
            if(user.length()==0)
            {
                txt_username.requestFocus();
                txt_username.setError("Username cant be empty");
            }

            else if(pass.length()==0){
                txt_password.requestFocus();
                txt_password.setError("Password cant be empty");
            }

            else

            {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,Homepage.class));
            }
        }
    };

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(login_click);

    View.OnClickListener signup_click = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,Registration.class));

        }
    };
    btn_signup.setOnClickListener(signup_click);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
 }
```

and [here](http://iguideph-001-site1.btempurl.com/getpics.php) my JSON.

Hope you can help me :)